# Paypal Upload Command - How to encrypt/secure dynamically generated payment amounts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, encryption, paypal

Alright so I saw a question similar to this but thought my situation was a little different and warranted a question. So I am working on a site that allows you to select from two dropdowns. I'm using jQuery to keep track of when these drop downs change. Then based off of the change I update the PayPal hidden form(Cart Upload Command).

Then once the user is done selecting the options they click the checkout button which takes them to the PayPal page that shows them the items they selected and they can begin the checkout process through PayPal. It sounds so easy when I say it like this but then I read that it needs to be encrypted. My question is how do I go about encrypting a dynamically generated form. They suggest using the PayPal button creation tool. Well that would make sense if I had a static amount, but I do not.

**HTML**

```
<label for="space-selector">Select Space</label>
<select class="form-control" id="space-selector" name="space-selector">
    <option value="150">10' x 10'</option>
    <option value="225">20' x 10'</option>
    <option value="300">30' x 10'</option>
    <option value="500">Custom</option>
</select>
<label for="parkingpass-selector">2 Day Parking Pass - $50</label>
<select class="form-control" id="parkingpass-selector" name="parkingpass-selector">
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="50">Yes</option>
</select>   

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="jestewart.11@gmail.com">
    <input type="text" name="item_name_1" value="Space Selected" readonly>
    <input type="text" name="amount_1" value="1.00"readonly>
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="1.75">
    <input type="text" name="item_name_2" value="Parking Pass" readonly>
    <input type="text" name="amount_2" value="2.00" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="2.50">
    <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function (){
    //space selector change
    $("select[name=space-selector]").change( function () {
        //update the hidden form values based off of selectors
        $("input[name=item_name_1]").val($(this).find(":selected").text());
        $("input[name=amount_1]").val($(this).find(":selected").val());
    });

    //parking pass selector change
    $("select[name=parkingpass-selector]").change( function () {
        //update the hidden form values based off of selectors
        $("input[name=item_name_2]").val($(this).find(":selected").text());
        $("input[name=amount_2]").val($(this).find(":selected").val());
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle to show you functionality. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qS2G9/2/)

Comment: You don't "encrypt the form". That's pointless. You encrypt the COMMUNICATIONS, e.g. use `https`

Comment: okay so I should get an SSL then correct?

Comment: Correct. It is a terrible idea to do *any sort of important anything* not over SSL.

Comment: Right but what stops anyone from copy and pasting my source code and making fraudulent payments. The SSL doesn't protect against that.

Comment: @j0hnstew I'm in the same situation. Too bad no one has come up with a solution for this. Guess I'll keep hunting!

Comment: @Marc B: What do you mean encrypting form is pointless? If someone changes the form contents they can buy things at tampered prices, right?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need encrypting the amount and others. The only important thing is to make ALL verifications on the server.

Paypal has an API who permise that. IPN

Some links :
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html